# CXF Rest service code provider

Tags: android, web-services, rest, oauth-2.0, cxf

I am creating simple REST API with OAuth2 authentication. I use Apache CXF, and the only third party app (consumer) that I will have for beginning will be Android application.

I was wondering if I must have redirectURL set for my

> org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.grants.code.ServerAuthorizationCodeGrant

I want just to return authorization code as JSON to my application and continue with OAuth protocol from there.

On the app, I plan to mimic form with POST request which will also send username/password to authorization grant service. Once I get response I will use authorization code to call access token service.

Is this OK, or there is better approach to programmatically do OAuth from Android APP as a client? I know about Spring OAuth for Android, but don't want to use it until I try simpler implementation.

Best Regards!